# How can I close all notifications of a page before unload it (without use Window#onunload)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications

I have a page that notifies the user about server updates, using [window.webkitNotifications](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification).

It's not a Google Chrome extension.

I want to close all page notifications before the page unload.
I'm trying to do it with:

```
var notifications = new Array();

// ...
var popup = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(...);
// ...
notifications.push(popup);

// ...
function closeAll(){
  for (notification in notifications) {
    notifications[notification].cancel();
  }
}

//...
$(window).unload(function() {
  closeAll();
});
```

But the notifications are not closed when I reloads the page.
I found this issue on Chromium project: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40262

How can I ensure that page notifications are closed without use the Window#onunload ?

Comment: i just ran into this issue today, it doesn't seem like that bug ever got fixed either, sucks. If the user refreshes the page the notification is just left there handing. Did you ever find a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you can add some javascript to the notification popup and settimeout withing the actual popup, that way it will close eventually.

I will have to try and test this out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :)

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    closeAll();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the `beforeunload` event instead of `unload`.